# Write output data to csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing a short piece of code in python to check the status code of a list of URLS. The steps are 
1. read the URL's from a csv file.
2. Check request code
3. Write the status code request into the csv next to the checked URL

The first two steps I've managed to do but I'm stuck with writing the output of the requests into the same csv, next to the urls. Please help.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
from multiprocessing import Pool

file = open('innovators.csv', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
urls = file.readlines()


def checkurl(url):

    try:
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print('HTTPError: {}'.format(e.code) + ', ' + url)

    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print('URLError: {}'.format(e.reason) + ', ' + url)

    else:
        print('200' + ', ' + url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(processes=1)
    result = p.map(checkurl, urls)

with open('innovators.csv', 'w') as f:
    for line in file:
        url = ''.join(line)
        checkurl(urls + "," + checkurl)
```

Comment: Read up on [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The `.readlines()` operation leaves the `file` object at the end of file. When you attempt to loop through the lines of `file` again, without first rewinding it (`file.seek(0)`) or closing and opening it again (`file.close()` followed by opening again), there are no lines remaining. Always recommended to use `with open(...) as file` construct to ensure file is closed when operation is finished.

Additionally, there appears to be an error in your input to `checkurl`. You have added a list (`urls`) to a string (`","`) to a function (`checkurl`).
You probably meant for this section to read

```
with open('innovators.csv', 'w') as f:
    for line in urls:
        url = ''.join(line.replace('\n','')) # readlines leaves linefeed character at end of line
        f.write(url + "," + checkurl(url))
```

The `checkurl` function should `return` what you are intending to place into the csv file. You are simply printing to standard output (screen). Thus, replace your `checkurl` with

```
def checkurl(url):

  try:
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    ret='0'
  except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    ret='HTTPError: {}'.format(e.code)

  except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    ret='URLError: {}'.format(e.reason)

  else:
    ret='200'
  return ret
```

or something equivalent to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Save the status in a dict. and convert it to dataframe. Then simply send it to a csv file. str(code.getcode()) will return 200 if the url is connecting else it will return an exception, for which i assigned status as '000'. So your csv file will contain url,200 if URL is connecting and url,000 if URL is not connecting.

```
    status_dict={}
    for line in lines:
      try:
           code = urllib.request.urlopen(line)
           status = str(code.getcode())
           status_dict[line] = status
        except:
            status = "000"
            status_dict[line] = status
    df = pd.Dataframe(status_dict)
    df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```